# Sorting, pagination, searching jQuery datatable search side processing doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatable, pagination

I'm using PHP + jQuery datatable server processing code and able to list out data (via JSON) in the table but sorting, pagination and searching doesn't work. It loads all the data in table on load and request/response is same for sorting columns, searching with any data and pagination numbering.

Client side:

```
$(".machines-data").dataTable({

                aLengthMenu: [ [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "-1"], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "All"] ],
                iDisplayLength: 5,
                searching: true,
                "aaSorting": [],
                columnDefs: [ { orderable: true } ],
                "bServerSide": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,

                "ajax": { "url": "/machines/server.php", "type": "POST", "dataType": "json", "cache": false },

                    "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "ip" },
            { "data": "machine" },
            { "data": "status" }
        ]

            });
```

JSON response:

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"45","iTotalDisplayRecords":"45","aaData":[["1","xx.yy.xx.yy","machine1","Completed"],[["1","xx.yy.xx.yy","machine2","Completed"]] .. 45 rows}
```

Server side:

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(true);

if($_POST) {

    $aColumns = array( 'id', 'ip', 'machine','status' );

    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    $sTable = "1_machines";

    $gaSql['user']       = "root";
    $gaSql['password']   = "pwd";
    $gaSql['db']         = "machines";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";

    function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
    {
        header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
        die( $sErrorMessage );
    }

    if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
    }

    if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
    }

    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }

    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= "`".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ".
                    ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`)
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "started_on" )
            {
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? ' - ' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );

    exit (0);

}

?>
```

Comment: Is your AJAX operation being called and responding without an error? Have you checked your browser's network monitor to watch this in real-time? Have you checked your JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes halfer. There is no js error even JSON response is fine like i mentioned but sorting, pagination and searching gives same response but the problem is nothing works except displaying data in table (that is also doesn't obey iDisplayLength).

Comment: which version of datatables are you using?

Comment: DataTables 1.10.6 almost latest.

Comment: Updated datatable to 1.10.7 but no luck. I guess version has nothing to do because it is almost latest. Can someone please take a look and help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, in my case was that i was using the param 'ajax' instead of 'sAjaxSource'

To solve this i use 'sAjaxSource' at the moment to apply the datatable pluging to my table

Answer (score 0):

Finally i'm happy that i have resolved the issue, the problem was with ajax data POST and server processing was GET. Used datatable+php server side processing php code and client side something like this:

```
$(".machines-data").dataTable({

    aLengthMenu: [ [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "-1"], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "All"] ],
    iDisplayLength: 5,
    searching: true,
    "aaSorting": [],
    columnDefs: [ { orderable: true } ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bDestroy": true,

    "bProcessing": true,                
    "serverSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "aLengthMenu: [ [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "-1"], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "All"] ],
    iDisplayLength: 5,
    searching: true,
    "aaSorting": [],
    columnDefs: [ { orderable: true } ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bDestroy": true,

    "bProcessing": true,                
    "serverSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/machines/server.php",

});
```